# getting current clicked element and add attribute in jquery Is not for working for child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stanze/7etf32qu/)

I am trying to get the clicked element in the DOM Tree, and where i have clicked in the same element the attribute has to be appended, again if i click the same element it has to check if its present it has to be removed.

Current Behavior : when i click an element i am getting the element (p, div, option,etc.,) in alert., but the ISSUE is when i am adding attribute its getting added to the parent div.

**Updated : when Ajax happens the attributes are being removed.**

JS :

```
$('#search-refine-bar').on('click', function(e) {
    var eventNode = e.target.nodeName;
    var refineChil = $('#search-refine-bar').children();
    var refineHasAttr = $('refineChil').attr({
        tabindex: "-1",
        focus: "focus"
    });
    alert(eventNode)
    if ($("#search-refine-bar").is('[focus]')) {
        alert(eventNode + " ----- " + 'attribute exists should be removed');
        $(this).removeAttr('tabindex focus style')
    } else {
        alert(eventNode + " ----- " + ' NO attribute exists...adding attribute');
        $(this).attr({
            tabindex: "-1",
            focus: "focus"
        }).css({
            "border": "1px solid #f00"
        });
    }
});
```

Appreciate your help :)

Comment: trying using this, instead of $(this)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add/remove the attribute from [e.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).

Inside the event handler `this` refers the target of the handler(in this case `#search-refine-bar`), but since you want the actual element that was clicked you can use the `target` property of the [event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)

```
$(e.target).removeAttr('tabindex focus style')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/boo6mcdk/)

Comment: Adding is working fine, tnx for that but it has to remove when we click the other element and add {attribute} to the current clicked element.

Comment: i did arun, but the attributes are not being removed (tabindex , focus) it remains same.. :( 
And even after ajax call the attributes it self are removing, do i need to add any setTimeOut Function..

Comment: The code he is using anyway is not DRY. Id better use toggle jquery function. Much more simple

Comment: @ArunPJohny : Can we use settTimeout function? after Ajax Call, Because when ever the click happens, its repainting the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do it that way. Use jquery toggle function or add a class if it has the properties. Its the best approach.

Comment: i cannot use toggle, every element is painted dynamically. so it wont figure out which element user has clicked.